# @metaplex-foundation/js .findByMint() getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBuffer')

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js, node.js, js

I am using Node.js

I am trying to get NFT metada but getting this error:

```
file:///home/tiosam/sns-tw-bot/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/plugins/nftModule/pdas.mjs:10
  return Pda.find(programId, [Buffer.from('metadata', 'utf8'), programId.toBuffer(), mint.toBuffer()]);
                                                                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBuffer')
    at findMetadataPda (file:///home/tiosam/sns-tw-bot/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/plugins/nftModule/pdas.mjs:10:91)
    at Object.handle (file:///home/tiosam/sns-tw-bot/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/plugins/nftModule/operations/findNftByMint.mjs:43:44)
    at Task.callback (file:///home/tiosam/sns-tw-bot/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/plugins/operationModule/OperationClient.mjs:40:31)
    at file:///home/tiosam/sns-tw-bot/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/Task.mjs:58:50
    at Disposable.run (file:///home/tiosam/sns-tw-bot/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/Disposable.mjs:22:36)
    at Task.forceRun (file:///home/tiosam/sns-tw-bot/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/Task.mjs:47:23)
    at Task.run (file:///home/tiosam/sns-tw-bot/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/Task.mjs:29:19)
    at txInfo (file:///home/tiosam/sns-tw-bot/test.js:24:64)
    at file:///home/tiosam/sns-tw-bot/test.js:12:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Node.js v17.9.0
```

When using:

await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({tokenMint}).run();

My code:

```
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { Metaplex } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";

const conn = new anchor.web3.Connection('PRIVATE RPC', 'confirmed');
const metaplex = new Metaplex(conn);

const txQuery = await conn.getTransaction('2Rgcsjea27NvvjVE3t68aKHCPmuq4zsat9uAaqoD6CMwTGF1n3EXu5kKXYtCq4XMgw6cTUsDVzXo136yGAj5MD5H', 'confirmed');

let accountIndexToken = txQuery.transaction.message.instructions[1].accounts[2];
let tokenMint = txQuery.transaction.message.accountKeys[accountIndexToken];
let nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({tokenMint}).run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js/blob/7feaad60f3f0dd9a3afc39f02dba1eba5f4fe5e4/packages/js/src/plugins/nftModule/NftClient.ts#L123-L126

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js/blob/7feaad60f3f0dd9a3afc39f02dba1eba5f4fe5e4/packages/js/src/plugins/nftModule/operations/findNftByMint.ts#L66-L105

The nft should be:

```
let nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({mintAddress: tokenMint}).run();
```